General reasoning as numerical optimization?
Has anyone tried to formalize the idea that reasoning is numerical optimization? We prefer to hold beliefs that satisfy certain criteria, such as consistency, usefulness, simplicity, completeness, and reliability. We could assign a number to how well the criteria are satisfied, and attempt to optimize the number. And the idea is that the process of optimization, passing through intermediate values step by step, could be analogous to a series of reasoning steps. Each step moves from a less preferable set of beliefs to a more preferable set of beliefs.
Has anyone made a good attempt at this type of thing?
Of course there is Bayesian inference, which is numerical. But Bayesian inference is not a model of reasoning in the sense that first order logic is a model of reasoning; Bayesian inference is a model of ideal conclusions, omitting the intermediate reasoning steps. And no human is capable of performing exact Bayesian inference on nontrivial real-world problems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Morgenstern_utility_theorem

I don’t know specifically but I’m studying logic, proof theory, and computer science right now and I believe it provides the techniques you want, especially automated theorem proving. Sometimes it feels like something should be automizable but then there are surprising difficulties when a problem turns out to be undecidable. Based on your description, the concepts that are already well-defined logically are consistency, completeness and probably simplicity. The ones you would need to research or develop would be mathematical definitions of usefulness and reliability.
Then, there would be an entire class of algorithms that try to optimize a collection of beliefs. In your case it sounds like the algorithm has two aspects, it can choose to include or exclude a proposition, and it can also negate a proposition. The algorithm can be deterministic or stochastic.
It exists, and it’s what I’m studying to try to be able to do right now. You can start with propositions in first-order logic. Then define meta-logical properties in a “second copy” of first order logic that describes the properties of the first copy. For example, a collection of formulae \Phi is inconsistent if \Phi \vdash \phi \wedge \Phi \vdash \neg \phi. So you need to define a first-order theory of \vdash.
I am pretty sure you then need a third tier to the system. This would make use of conditional rules on entailments, as sequent calculus does. So you could have rules like “if P in context \Gamma entails Q, and Q reduces the score of the theory \Phi, then derive not-P”.
Happy to collaborate if you wish.
